# Is "dum" missing in the sentence "Mi atendis pli ol horo"?

Tags: prepositions, accusative

One can say "Mi atendis horon", where *horo* has the accusative mark as an [indication of a time-length](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/mezuro.html#i-gug). However, we usually don't use the accusative after *ol*. Can we directly transform the sentence into "Mi atendis pli ol horo", or we have to restore the preposition (like in "Mi atendis dum pli ol horo" or "Mi atendis pli ol dum horo")?

Comment: I think it's either accusative or with a preposition exclusively.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you need the accusative.

There are many examples in the Tekstaro that would illustrate.

- Tie ili estis devigataj atendi pli ol unu horon;
- Ned ne atendis pli ol kvin minutojn por la ekzameno
- Diskuto daŭris pli ol tri horojn.
- Litovoj dormas mezume ne pli ol 6 horojn:

There are also examples with a preposition.

- post ne pli ol du horoj
- En la daŭro de pli ol unu horo
- dum pli ol ses horoj

It's possible that there are counter examples (where neither an accusative nor a preposition is used), but I have not located any.